# Form not getting submitted after JS validation

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and I don't quite know how validation functions are handled. The validation I did works perfectly but the form doesn't get submitted even if the inputs are valid. May be it has to do with the syntax but I don't know how to get this work

here is the code...

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const username = document.getElementById('username');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const message = document.getElementById('message');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    checkInputs();
});

(function checkInputs() {
    //get the values from the inputs

    const usernameValue = username.value.trim();
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();
    const messageValue = message.value.trim();

    // name validation
    if (usernameValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(username, 'Name can not be blank');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(username);
    }
    // email validation
    if (emailValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(email, 'Email can not be blank');
    } else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
        setErrorFor(email, 'Email is not valid');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(email);
    }
    // message validation
    if (messageValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(message, 'Message can not be blank');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(message);
    }
    // showing success
    // alert("Form submitted successfully!");
})();

(function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement; // .form-control
    const small = formControl.querySelector('small');

    // add error message inside the small tag

    small.innerText = message;

    //add error class
    formControl.className = 'form-control error';
})();

(function setSuccessFor(input) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = 'form-control success';
    window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";

})();

(function isEmail(email) {
    // checks if the email is in the correct format 
    // for example: ****@gmail.com
    const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
})();
```

This is the form

```html
<form action="confirm.php" method="POST" class="form" id="form" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-control">
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your name here" name="username" id="username">
        <small>Error message</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
        <label>Email: </label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Your email address" name="email" id="email">
        <small>Error message</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
        <label class="newsletter">Do you want my news letter? </label>
        <br><br>
        <label class="news" for="yes">Yes, please</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="news" name="news" value="yes" checked>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control message">
        <label>Drop me a line: </label><br>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message here" id="message" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea>
        <br> <small>Error message</small>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
    <input type="reset"></input>
</form>
```

and this is where I'm submitting it:

```html
<div class="container confirm">
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Confirmation</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="first"><br>
            &nbsp Your name: <span class = "name"><?php echo $_POST['username']; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="second"><br>
            &nbsp Your email: <span class="email"><?php echo $_POST['email']; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="third"><br>
            &nbsp Your message: <span class="message"><?php echo $_POST['message']; ?></span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <textarea name="line" id="line" cols="40" rows="7" readonly></textarea>
        <button style="margin-left:50%; margin-top: 10%;">confirm</button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe that checkInputs needs to return a boolean (valid, invalid, something like that), otherwise the form will not submit.

Comment: So where do you submit the form after you prevent it?

Comment: @epascarello I'm sending it to another php file using the post method. I tried sending it without the validation and it gets submitted, but doesn't work when I include the validation

Comment: So where do you submit it? You cancel the form action so it is never going to submit. You should only call `e.preventDefault();` if you do not want it to submit.

Comment: @darkmnemic I tried that but no luck

Comment: I am submitting it to another page that shows the information entered by the user like(name : someone, message: hi there)

Comment: Where/how do you submit it? I see nothing but an update of the page's href.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Not what you're submitting it *to* -- where you actually submit the form. You have a `submit` handler that prevents the default event action ("submit the form"), run a bunch of validation, then... AFAICT nothing. Setting the `href` does not submit a form in and of itself.

Comment: so what shall I do? what is your suggestion

Comment: As cfarhad alludes to, all of your functions appear to be wrapped in IIFE expressions, which doesn't make a lot of sense--you just want them to be functions. The page shouldn't work the way you want it to right now even ignoring that you never submit the form.

Comment: Actually, I'm not trying to make a working contact form. All I wanted to do was to show the input back to the user for confirmation. anyways I will try to find another way, thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you created [anonymous function](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_functions) , That is why they are undefined. You have to leave all it out

example :

```
function setSuccessFor(input) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement;
  formControl.className = "form-control success";
}
```

You must create a condition at the end of the function that will take you to a page if all the fields are full.

```js
  if (username.value && email.value && message.value) {
    window.location.href = "https://www.w3schools.com";
  }
```

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const username = document.getElementById("username");
const email = document.getElementById("email");
const message = document.getElementById("message");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  checkInputs();
});

function checkInputs() {
  //get the values from the inputs

  const usernameValue = username.value.trim();
  const emailValue = email.value.trim();
  const messageValue = message.value.trim();

  //name validation
  if (usernameValue === "") {
    setErrorFor(username, "Name can not be blank");
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(username);
  }
  //email validation
  if (emailValue === "") {
    setErrorFor(email, "Email can not be blank");
  } else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
    setErrorFor(email, "Email is not valid");
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(email);
  }
  //message validation
  if (messageValue === "") {
    setErrorFor(message, "Message can not be blank");
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(message);
  }

  if (username.value && email.value && message.value) {
    window.location.href = "https://www.w3schools.com";
  }
}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement; // .form-control
  const small = formControl.querySelector("small");

  //add error messafe inside the small tag

  small.innerText = message;

  //add error class
  formControl.className = "form-control error";
}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement;
  formControl.className = "form-control success";
}

function isEmail(email) {
  //checks if the email is in the correct format
  //for example: ****@gmail.com
  const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="confirm.php" method="POST" class="form" id="form">
    <div class="form-control">
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your name here" name="username" id="username">
        <small></small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
        <label>Email: </label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Your email address" name="email" id="email">
        <small></small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
        <label class="newsletter">Do you want my news letter? </label>
        <br><br>
        <label class="news" for="yes">Yes, please</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="news" name="news" value="yes" checked>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control message">
        <label>Drop me a line: </label><br>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message here" id="message" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea>
        <br> <small></small>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
    <input type="reset"></input>
</form>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Setting `window.location.href` does not submit a form. There's also only one anonymous function (the submit handler), maybe you mean IIFE? Fixing that would certainly fix *part* of the problem, but still not the actual form submission.

Comment: I did it like you suggested,. First I created a function called Validate then deleted the preventdafault function and used return false in each of the if statements  lastly a return true statement at the very bottom. Finally I used onsubmit" return Validate() "inside the form. Cheers!